# Trying to clean up the field.value of a field in Yup outside the render

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm trying to clear the **field.value** of a **Controller** field from **react-hook-forms** which is managed by **yup** through an external clean up function and it doesn't have access to the **field** that is generated by the `render` prop in the **Controller**.

This is my **Controller**:

```js
        <Controller
          name={name}
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <div className='relative w-full'>
              // {pruned code...}
              {showEmojiPicker && (
                <div className='absolute -top-48 right-10 z-10 shadow-2xl'>
                  <EmojiPicker
                    onEmojiClick={(emojiObject: EmojiClickData) => {
                      field.onChange(emojiObject.emoji);
                      handleEmojiClick(emojiObject);
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        />
```

Sadly, `control.setValue(name, ${value})` isn't a thing, as ChatGPT kept trying to suggest for me to use.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve my desired goal with `control.unregister(name)`.